# Matplotlib: How not to draw on the same image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save the visualization resutls of my program which outputs images under a certain path. However, each time when it saves the image, it saves over the one before.

```
if visualize:
                    # Visualize
                    plt.xlim((0, 640))
                    plt.ylim((0, 480))
                    plt.imshow(scipy.misc.imresize(img, (480, 640)))
                    # Projections
                    for edge in edges_corners:
                        plt.plot(proj_corners_gt[edge, 0], proj_corners_gt[edge, 1], color='g', linewidth=3.0)
                        plt.plot(proj_corners_pr[edge, 0], proj_corners_pr[edge, 1], color='b', linewidth=3.0)
                    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
                    #plt.show()
                    plt.savefig(outputdir + componentname + str(count) + '.png')

count = count + 1
```

In the end, I end up with like images that look like this:

[image]

[image]

There should be a way to "refresh" the image each time. Anyone knows what that update function is?

Comment: It looks like that you're writing on the same image file, `outputdir + componentname + str(count) + '.png'` over and over again. Where is `count` variable handled?

Comment: Files have different names so count seems to be working, however it keeps drawing on the previous images, which is the problem

Comment: [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html).

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, looking into and searching for matplotlib animations may also be useful.

Comment: Yes, `plt.clf()` should work then.

Comment: Yes, that function was the answer! If you can add it as answer, I can accept it.